# Duvida na atualização do Mapa da API do google maps!

Tags: google-maps

Boa tarde galera, estou com uma duvida aqui. Queria saber como é feita a atualização do mapa da API do google maps, pois o mapa do google é atualizado e tals e aparece todos os bairro da minha cidade, mas o do google maps API não aparece!!
Tem como eu atualizar ou eu baixo algum arquivo!! Alguém pode me ajudar pf!!

Comment: Poste o codigo para ajudar

Comment: Tem o código padrão do map, nesse link: 
[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple?hl=pt-br], porém o usuário não possui controle do mapa em sí